# How to make an arc on the rectangle?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I know I can use moveTo(), lineTo() method to draw irregular rectangle, but what if I want to creat an arc on the rectangle?

Here is my thought as below:
I add an arc() between two lineTo(), and shows below drawing.

```
function draw(){
    var c = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(40,40);
    ctx.lineTo(80,40);
    ctx.lineTo(80,80);
    ctx.arc(80,150,70,0.5*Math.PI,1.5*Math.PI,true);
    ctx.lineTo(80,260);
    ctx.lineTo(40,260);
    ctx.lineTo(40,40);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

[image: it's result I run for my code]

It's not the result I expected, I want to present the drawing like this which no line between the arc and rectangle.

[image: It's the result I expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply invert your arc drawing order. You are currently drawing it from 6 o'clock to 12 o'clock.

The key point here is that `arc` does include an `lineTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y)`, so you'll need to handle this.

If you wanted to keep this order, you'd have to `moveTo` 6 o'clock before drawing the arc, and `moveTo` 6 o'clock again after drawing the arc.

```js
function draw(){
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var rad = 70,
    w = 40,
    h = 220,
    x = 40,
    y = 40;
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y); // top left
    ctx.lineTo(x + w, y); // top right
    // draw a line to the end of your arc
    ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + (h - (rad * 2)) / 2);
    // move to the start of the arc (6 o'clock)
    ctx.moveTo(x + w, y + ((h - (rad * 2)) / 2) + rad * 2);
    // draw the arc
    ctx.arc(x + w, y + h/2, rad, 0.5*Math.PI, 1.5*Math.PI, true);
    // move again to the start of the arc (6 o'clock)
    ctx.moveTo(x + w, y + ((h - (rad * 2)) / 2) + rad * 2);
    ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h); // bottom right
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + h); // bottom left
    ctx.lineTo(x, y); // top right again
    ctx.stroke();
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" height="300"></canvas>
```

By inverting it, you can avoid these `moveTo` :

```js
function draw() {
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var rad = 70,
    w = 40,
    h = 220,
    x = 40,
    y = 40;
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y); // top left
  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y); // top right
  // to the start of the arc (12 o'clock)
  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + (h - (rad * 2)) / 2);
  // draw the arc
  ctx.arc(x + w, y + h / 2, rad, 1.5 * Math.PI, 0.5 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h); // bottom right
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + h); // bottom left
  ctx.lineTo(x, y); // top right again
  ctx.stroke();
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things: (1) The arc needs to be in a separate path, and (2) change the start and end points in a way that keeps the path open.

```
function draw(){
    var c = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(80,220);
    ctx.lineTo(80,260);
    ctx.lineTo(40,260);
    ctx.lineTo(40,40);
    ctx.lineTo(80,40);
    ctx.lineTo(80,80);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(80,150,70,0.5*Math.PI,1.5*Math.PI,true);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: thamks your reply,but It's not the result i expected.
I need one beginPath() to draw.